# PhpStorm - 502 Bad Gateway / Object not found Error 404

Tags: php, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide, gateway

This is my first post here. I followed instructions and explored all the internet on this topic, still didn't figure out the solution. Added interpreter as you can see on this screenshot:

[image: 1]

I created PHP Web Application as visible here:

[image: 2]

And after that I when I try to run it in any browser I get this message (Don't have reputation 10 so couldn't post it as 3rd picture):

> "Object not found!

The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

> Error 404
>
> localhost Apache/2.4.17 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2d PHP/5.6.20"

Please help me, I don't know what to do anymore. Thanks in advance!

EDIT 1:

So I figured out that my php file and all the other files (css, js, html, img) have to be in xamp/htdocs folder so I can run it manually by writing "localhost/filename.php" in address bar. It works only if my php file is exactly in htdocs folder. Otherwise when I try to run my file from folder where the rest of my project is and in address I add "localhost/projectfolder/homepage.php" I got message saying: "

> Warning: Unknown: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   Unknown on line 0
>
> Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required 'D:/xampp/htdocs/Damir
>   Jelusić/homepage.php' (include_path='D:\xampp\php\PEAR') in Unknown on
>   line 0"

I couldn't find a solution to this. Also I would like to be able to run my php page just by clickin little chrome icon in phpstorm. Tell me if it is possible. Cheers!

Comment: how does your vhost-configuration looks like?

Comment: I don't know how to check that but I doubt it's about it. Now I re-run my php storm and apparently it worked. 

I figured out I've put invalid link into my PHP Web Application and had some issues with blank spaces and č/ć in my folder name so I made sure there are no those and finally it works!